# Paleoclimatology Data

Tags: data

I have been looking for paleoclimatology data.  I have found some with NOAA ( http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/paleo/data.html ) but all the data is stored as a KMZ and a series of linking text and html files.  Does anyone know of vendors or sites that have this type of data in a better spatial format?  I am most interested in data around the Great Lakes.

Thanks...

Comment: Why not convert KML to format of your choosing? (If the data has all the information you need)

Comment: You don't say which GIS you're using but if it's ArcGIS it's certainly possible to import the KML files (Conversion Tools > From KML > KML to Layer). Also, can you point to a specific data source on the webpage that you reference? I can only find .zip and .txt files.

Comment: I am well aware of that, but they are KMZ files.  I have converted them to KML and imported them to shp (in Arc and QGIS) but they loose the data I want.  Everything gets bundled into a field that is all XML.  As I stated, all the KMZ are linked to Text files and websites.  I am hoping to find a source that has this all bundled into a spatial layer, not KMZ with weblinks.

Comment: KML has far too much freedom in its structures to make it easy to read everything in it into another spatial data format. I almost always have to write a custom XML parser in Python if I want anything other than x-y points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check these data: http://www.worldclim.org/past They contain:

- Last inter-glacial (LIG; ~120,000
- 140,000 years BP) Last glacial maximum (LGM; ~21,000 years BP)
- Mid-Holocene (~6000 BP)